# fnDraw is not working if I use modal in action button with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, datatables

On manual page refresh the modals are working fine. But when reloading the datatable with Ajax the popups stop working.

Below is my HTML and JavaScript code:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover mb-none" id="IVRFilesTable">
<thead>
    <tr class="primary">
        <th>IVR Name</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="tablediv">
<?php foreach($records as $row) {?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['ivrname']?></td>
        <td width="10%" class="actions text-center">
            <a href="#dialogRemoveSuppliers" id="removeIvr" data-id="<?php echo $row['id']?>" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Remove" class="mb-xs mt-xs mr-xs modal-with-zoom-anim modal-sizes"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg text-primary"></i></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php }?>
</tbody>
```

```
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/admin/manageivrs/removeivr",
  type: "POST",
  data: "ivrid="+ivrid,
  success: function (msg)
  {
    if(msg=='true')
    {
        var oTable = $('#IVRFilesTable').dataTable();
        oTable.fnClearTable();
              $("#IVRFilesTable").load(location.href+" #IVRFilesTable>*","");
        oTable.fnDraw();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: can you say what you have done to debug this and solve it, and link to any questions on SO which don't work for you

Comment: Yes @Mousey , Tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24642456/how-to-add-data-inside-datatable-using-jquery but here I use jquery load() function instead of fnAddData(). But still the pop ups r not working, every thing else is ok.

Comment: I don't see how you instantiate modal dialog but most likely the problem is that once table content is changed, event handler is no longer firing because of how you attach it. See [Why click event handler does not work](http://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-why-click-event-handler-does-not-work/) for more details. Post your code on how you open the modal dialog.